# How to generate a Data URI from an image file?

Tags: conversion, data

There are online tools like [duri.me](http://duri.me/) that allow to create a Data URI from an image file. Are there any tools that run locally on Linux to do the same?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Data URIs are usually just base64-encoded with the MIME-type stuck at the front. I use this homegrown script, which takes the filename as its first and only parameter and returns the data uri, already wrapped in `url('data:')`:

```
[0 1026 8:29:38] ~ % cat $(which cssify.sh)
#!/bin/sh
mimetype=$(file -bN --mime-type "$1")
content=$(base64 -w0 < "$1")
echo "url('data:$mimetype;base64,$content')"
```

Comment: I needed to replace `-w0` with `-b0`

Comment: On BSD (macOS) use `base64` without parameters as it doesn't break the string by default. Code:  
`#!/usr/bin/env bash`  
`echo "url('data:$(file -bN --mime-type "$1");base64,$(base64 < "$1")')"`